# How to test if a connection to a Db is established successfully?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, ado.net, connection

I want to write a unit-test which asserts a connection string is valid so that a conenction is established to a SQL Db.

if I have :

```
string connectionString = GetCOnenctionString();
bool conenctionEstablished = false;
```

How can I set 'conenctionEstablished' variable's value as a result of a check to a Db with the 'connectionString' provided?

So that I can use it in an Assert.

Comment: Code Unit tests should not hit real databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to connect in a try/catch then set conenctionEstablished based on whether the connection succeeds or not.

Comment: So, no exception thrown after a connection.Open() ensures the fact that there is a successfull connection initiated?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you are running on a System.Data.dll version earlier than .NET 4 with Reliability Update 1 (kb2533523), then opening a `SqlConnection` can give you a pooled connection that was disconnected while the connection was in the pool. To really prove that a connection is alive, execute any `SqlCommand` (such as `select 1` suggested below by evpo).

Comment: That said, since in your particular case you only want to open one connection ever with that connection string, so pooled connections are not a factor, so just calling `Open()` should be enough. My other comment is in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

It is not going to be a "pure" unit test because your database is real but any way. I would use a try catch block and after opening the connection execute a "select 1" statement with ExecuteNonQuery(). At the end of the try block set the flag to true.

Answer (score 2):

There are different states available, look at this:

```
private static void OpenSqlConnection(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: {0}", connection.ServerVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is an Enumeration called [Connectionstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx)
so you can assert if the connection is closed, open connecting ,etc.

```
Assert.AreEqual(ConnectionState.Connecting, sqlcon.State);
```

Answer (score 0):

We could rather check, if the connection is open or not, by using the following code:

```
using System.Data;

if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    return true;
}
else 
{
    return false;
}
```